# How can I use both on() and delegate() for the same ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a 3 tiered data display:

Basic HTML structure:

```
<article id="container">

    <header>
    <h1>Tier One (PHP Loop) <a href="#" class="confirm">X</a></h1>
    </header>
    <section> <!-- Filled by ajax call from Tier 1 -->

         <h2>Tier Two <a href="#" class="confirm">X</a></h2>
         <section>  <!-- Filled by ajax call from Tier 2 -->

             <p>Tier Three <a href="#" class="confirm">X</a></p>
             <p>Tier Three <a href="#" class="confirm">X</a></p>
             <p>Tier Three <a href="#" class="confirm">X</a></p>
             <p>Tier Three <a href="#" class="confirm">X</a></p>
             <p>Tier Three <a href="#" class="confirm">X</a></p>
             <p>Tier Three <a href="#" class="confirm">X</a></p>

         </section>

    </section>

</article>
```

I'm attempting to set up a database delete button via an ajax call instigated by a click in each tier.

---

```
$('a.confirm').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ }); 
});
```

Works for tier 1, but **not** for tiers 2 and 3 ...

---

```
$('#container').delegate('a.confirm', 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ }); 
});
```

or

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a.confirm', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ }); 
});
```

Works for tiers 2 and 3, but **not** for tier 1 ...

---

*Everything* else in the function is pretty much identical. There are a few variables but they all pull the same essential  `data` from the anchor (ids, etc), then the ajax just sends php differing data from the handler.

I can easily just duplicate the jQuery code and change the handler. But I'm sure there has to be a way to somehow combine the handlers into one statement.

I have attempted things such as `$('#container, header').delegate()` or `$('#container, h1').delegate()` but that hasn't made a difference.

I also tried `bind()` and `live()` with no luck.

Is this possible?

I'm using jQuery 191 and jQuery UI 1114 if that makes a difference.

Comment: The delegated version (whether with .delegate() or .on()) should work for all three tiers, not just for 2 & 3. And it *does* work here: https://jsfiddle.net/mewnsmuf/

Comment: @nnnnnn I'd live to but have no clue how to implement an ajax call in a fiddle.

Comment: Is the problem that the click handler is not called, or that the Ajax doesn't work? You can do a dummy ajax call in a fiddle, but I thought the problem you were describing was that the click handler doesn't get called. In the fiddle I linked to in my previous comment the click works fine for all tiers. (Sorry, I edited my previous comment before I saw your reply.)

Comment: @nnnnnn the click handler in tier 1 isn't being called for anything other then the first `on('click')` function I posted above (but then tier 2 and 3 don't work). The ajax works fine, it's merely the three click handlers I can't get to all function at once.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote, whoever cast it.

Comment: So what is different about your code and my fiddle? A single handler works in the fiddle...

Comment: @nnnnnn the difference is that tier 2 and 3 are not part of DOM on load. They are both loaded through ajax calls. Your code works for tiers 2 and 3, but then not for tier 1. So far only a straight call to `$('a.confirm').on()` or `$('a.confirm').click()` are seeing it as a handler on tier 1.

Comment: I have no doubt this all due to my error somewhere now. I'll keep digging for repeated calls, I'm not seeing any, but I may be missing something.

Comment: For the delegated version (as in the fiddle) it shouldn't matter if the content is loaded dynamically after the call to .on() - just as long as the #container element already exists before the call to .on(). This is a very common, proven technique, so there must be something else going on in your code (in the code not shown).

Comment: @nnnnnn Okay.. I'll examine. Thank you. I was (mistakenly) under the impression that `on()` wouldn't work for dynamically loaded content and I had to use `delegate()`. I'll rewrite. Thanks again.

Comment: One final comment: .on()'s behaviour depends on how many arguments you pass it and which element it is called for. The first way above will *not* work for elements added later and is equivalent to .click(). The second way above with a selector as the second argument is equivalent to .delegate(), and actually all .delegate() does internally is call .on(). Good luck!

Comment: @nnnnnn y'all are correct (not that I ever thought differently after all I'm asking :) ).. I removed a jeditables include and you are right.. there's something in the calls inside my jeditables that is causing a conflict. Without including jeditable handlers, the `on( 'click', 'element')` works for all 3 tiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the **`.on()`** method.

What you looking for is event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** as following :

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a.confirm', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ }); 
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this. It fails on tier 1 as well. Tier 1 never sees the click event. Only works for tiers 2 and 3. Sorry edited the questions. I forgot to include that.

Comment: @Scott then your problem is elsewhere, because the code in this answer should target all three. You probably have duplicate #container id's.

Comment: @KevinB hmm... just word searched the php and js files for the container ID..(only 1 php page and 1 custom jquery external) I only find 1 ID occurrence in both files. But I'll keep looking.

Comment: @KevinB you're correct, This appears to be a localized issue.

Comment: If that container div is inside a loop, it would be inserted into the page multiple times even if it is only in your php file once.